# comparing strings and list index error

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to run this program in python but it keeps giving me an error that list index is out of range for the if statement line. But it does print out the "match found" where it has to.

```
import csv
with open('/Users/jadhav/Documents/Hubble files/m4_hubble_1.csv') as f:
    bl = [[],[],[],[],[]]
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for r in reader:
        for c in range(5):
            bl[c].append(r[c])

print "The files have now been sorted into lists"
for c in range(0,999):
    if bl[4][c] == "HST_10775_64_ACS_WFC_F814W":
        print "match found"
    else:
        del bl[0][c] 
        del bl[1][c] 
        del bl[2][c] 
        del bl[3][c]
        del bl[4][c]
```

Comment: You might want to tag your question with the language you are using.

Comment: how did you choose your range?

Comment: There are a total of 1000 elements for each of the lists, so I choose 999

Comment: Ranges in Python are half-open (the upper limit is excluded), so if there are 1000 elements you want `range(0, 1000)` or just `range(1000)`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the files have less than 999 lines, so `bl` doesn't grow enough. Add exception handling, compute the maximum index beforehand or iterate over the elements differently.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't delete items from a list over which you are iterating.

First you're checking `bl[0][0]`, then deleting `bl[0][0]`, causing the later ones to be shifted down. There are now 999 items in the list.

Then you're checking `bl[0][1]`, which was previously `bl[0][2]` (the original  `bl[0][1]` is now `bl[0][0]`).

And so on.

Eventually, when `c` is 500, you have only 500 items in the list. `IndexError`!